# SailsJS is unstable on Amazon elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, sails.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, waterline

I'm using sails on an elastic beanstalk auto-scaling deployment, but things are misbehaving, it seems very unstable.

For example, (seemingly) out of the blue the following custom model method, that had been running fine for the last 3 months or so, stopped working

```
var obj = this.toObject();
obj.permissions = obj.getPermissions();
```

Changing the code to

```
var obj = this.toObject();
obj.permissions = this.getPermissions();
```

fixed the problem, but only after bringing the site down for a couple of hours.

Another example

```
User.findOne({ id: 'someIDstring' }, function(err, user) { ... });
```

Suddenly started returning a user model with its associations populated with embedded objects... which when saved started throwing waterline errors due to the embedded records.

My guess is that the dependencies of sails are being updated when elastic beanstalk is spinning up new servers, and some of those dependencies are changing the way that sails is running.

Or I'm completely off the mark and something else is happening. Either way I'm getting very nervous that a rather busy site is going to fall over at any time.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what's going on. Or have had any similar experiences.

Muchos gracias.

Comment: You can check your event stream on AWS console to see if instances are replaced. How are you downloading dependencies? Do you think the upstream is providing a different version of the library which is not compatible with your code as new instances come.

Comment: What version of sails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess is that the dependencies of sails are being updated when
>   elastic beanstalk is spinning up new servers,

If you're running `npm install` as part of your production deployment on scaling infrastructure, you're going to have problems. You should pre-package your application with npm into a single tarball and install that. What if someone unpublishes one of your dependencies? The npm dependency graph can be dozens of layers deep. If anything changes at any of those levels, you could see problems.

If you have critical deployment issues/questions, contact the company: [sailsjs.com/about](https://sailsjs.com/about)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you expand your answer to outline how I would package up the tarball. I'm currently using EB CLI to deploy the code base from a git repo. Would you advise committing a tar of each stable release to git and deploying from that?

Comment: Also we are using bcrypt which will not work on ubuntu if complied on mac

Comment: Make sure you have a `package-lock.json`